# Recovering DNA from an RNA-extraction/purification kit

Tags: molecular-biology

We are extracting RNA from single insects with the later purpose of performing RNA-seq. We are using the RNeasy Plus Miniki from Qiagen, which involves the use of eliminator columns [as you can see here page 7](https://www.qiagen.com/us/resources/download.aspx?id=16b8f578-d192-4613-ae32-8e02e0b0fa77&lang=en).

However, we would love to be able to recover some DNA to perform a PCR which would help us confirm the insect species we are dealing with. Ideally, we would like to do this without losing any RNA-containing material. We were therefore wondering whether it was possible to retrieve some DNA from a column, which would otherwise be discarded ? Does anyone have experience with this ?

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is DNA in your RNA extraction?

Comment: We have run it on a gel yes, there was none after the DNA removal step.

Comment: Test it with a PCR; gels are about the least sensitive method of looking for DNA. almost every RNA extraction contains some DNA. So long as you didn't add DNase that is.

Comment: The idea however is that we would use material which would be otherwise discarded, we are reluctant to take away some of our pool of RNA.

Comment: The procedures for DNA and RNA extraction are almost identical; the difference is a small change in pH. You could try collecting flow through from the sample binding step and then put it through a DNA column or DNA extraction procedure (precipitation). Surely the cDNA generated in the RNAseq will result in something you can use for ID of the species; even the RNAseq results should tell you that.

Comment: We would rather not use the cDNA generated in the RNAseq process because we are extracting from single small insects, and we might have just enough for RNAseq.
The DNA/RNA separation step happens on a column : the DNA will bind to the eliminator column while the RNA will flow through. Then the RNA is placed on an other column to be further purified and eluted. Which is why w would like to recover the DNA from the previous column.

Comment: Simple - don't use the eliminator columns... Note that most RNAseq preps use in the fmol range of sample loaded and have a PCR amplification step to help you get there.